# Coding email addresses directly in HTML is bad, right? What is a better easy solution?

Tags: php, html, email

I have a site that will display a large number of members publicly with their contact info.  It is a bad idea to simply spit their emails up on the page in HTML due to spamming, etc., right?

So I am sure there a a thousand ways to deal with this.  And I have seen recommendations ranging from using "name[at]blah[dot]com" (which just doesn't seem that much more secure).  I guess the logical step would be to utilize phpmail or swiftmailer or something along those lines?  Both look like they are right at the edge of my PHP skills and would cause me some headaching before I could get them to work right.

Is there an easier solution? Can anyone suggest one with the best simple-to-effective ratio?

I am grabbing the info from member-entered SQL data.

Comment: An important consideration is: why do you need to display their emails publicly at all?  If you want to let people contact them, can you do it through some internal system?

Comment: What is the back-end of the site? Plain HTML or are you using something like Drupal/Joomla?
My point is, I know Drupal and it would almost certainly have a plugin to allow you to do this -- maybe with a selection box for the addressee. Other systems will have a way to do this too. So you may not have to write any code at all.

Comment: @tandu The site is for jazz musicians, and I would like people to be able to contact them.  That is one of the reasons for having their profiles displayed.  I know I can do it internally, but like I said.. it would be the first time for me doing something like this and I am not sure what is the most headache-free solution.

Comment: @CJBrew The back end is custom PHP.  I only really have experience with Wordpress as a CMS and it didn't seem to fit the idea of this site, so I just put together my own backend.  It's really just a big gallery that displays thumbnails and short descriptions, but has some funky AJAX and jQuery stuff going on to show additional information as the user hovers around the gallery.  Cool filtering according to instrument/style/influences too.  I just don't know the best way to implement "contacting".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better solution to displaying their emails or creating a `mailto:` link would be to add a "Click Here to Email" button that gives the user a simple form (From address, Subject, Body). When this form is posted, create the email server-side and send it to the recipient.

If you implement the above system, do not simply output the recipient's email address into a hidden input field. Instead, write out a unique identifier and then look up the email address on the backend. This way, the recipient's address is never available to be scraped by a bot or malicious user.

Comment: This is the way to go I guess.  Your info gives me a good starting direction.  Do phpmailer or swiftmailer give a big advantage over figuring this out on my own?  I only say that because it seems like as I have been learning PHP the material that I've found in books and online are ... in many cases .. outdated, insecure, or *nothing* like how things are actually done "in real life".

Comment: In a lot of cases, PHP tutorials are intended to teach you how the language works rather than how to write a "real program". Best practices, good algorithms and experience are what separate "tutorial code" from "production code".

Answer (score 3):

What do you want: send a mail or display mail? If send, use PHP's mail function, it's easy to use, won't cause headache. If you want to display only, first consider if you *really need* to display. If you really need, then either replace @ and . with [] or something like this - not sure whether robots know this or not or even safer: display them only on click via AJAX and PHP. Spambots and mail-collecting-bots cannot click.

Comment: Good tips.  Although I am going more for mailing, if I need to display in the future I will keep your AJAX idea in mind.  Thank you.